# How to move windows 7 boot partition from one drive to another?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I have the windows 7 boot partition on a raid array that has been having some serious issues lately. The current system is installed on a separate disk, however the boot partition is on the aforementioned array.

Everything works fine as it is, but in case they fail, what do I need to do to to move said partition to the working drive and just disconnect the failing ones?

Comment: What RAID configuration is it?

Comment: It's a raid0 array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create/move Windows 7 boot related files to another disk/partition using this guide:

[Move Windows 7 boot files to another drive](http://www.boyans.net/MoveWindows7BootFilesToAnotherDrive.html).

Please post back if it has worked for you - boot sequence is always:

first disk, active partition (on UEFI -> firmware boot manager, Windows boot manager)