# Remove Windows 7 bootloader from second drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, bootloader

I have a Windows 7 installation on a PC with a 128GB SSD and a 2TB HDD.

I installed the OS on the 128GB SSD but I forgot to remove the 2TB HDD befopre installing Windows 7, so it installed the system on the SSD, but the bootloader on the HDD.

Now I changed the SSD due to problems related to the old one. I re-installed Windows 7 removing the HDD first and everything works fine.

The only problem is that I still have the old bootloader installed on the 2TB HDD, how can I remove it completely?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/531922/how-to-move-windows-7-boot-partition-from-one-drive-to-another

Comment: What exactly is left? The `Boot` directory? Or are you concerned about the boot sector?

Comment: if all you want is to delete the boot partition from the 2TB hdd,  I would use a linux livecd (parted magic) and boot up into it and delete the partition. Or get to the recovery mode of the windows 7 cmd line and use diskpart to delete the 100MB hidden partition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the superfluous drive out of the boot sequence. That still allows access to the files on the second disk, but ignores the second disk boot record. Then you can clean up the second drive at your leisure.